# Changing horizontal axis in plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the current code:

```
library(plotrix)
upperlimit = c(6.77, 26.79, 29.29, 28.98)
lowerlimit = c(-7.31, 3.85, 4.13, 2.10)
mean = c(-0.27, 15.32, 16.71, 15.54)

df = data.frame(cbind(upperlimit,lowerlimit,mean))
plot(df$mean, ylim = c(-10,30), xlim = range(1,4))
plotCI(df$mean,y=NULL, uiw=df$upperlimit-df$mean, liw=df$mean-df$lowerlimit, err="y",      pch=20,  scol = "black", add=TRUE)
abline(a= 0, b= 0, col="red", lty=3)
```

This gives me a boxplot with confidence intervals:

[image]

However, I would like the horizontal axis to display "noon", "3pm", "6pm", "9pm" instead. Is this possible? (Or do I have to use ggplot)?

I tried to modify the line from `xlim = range(1,4)` to `xlim = c("noon", "3pm", "6pm", "9pm")`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn off the default x axis (with `xaxt="n"`) and draw your own (specifying whatever `labels=` you want)

```
plot(df$mean, ylim = c(-10,30), xlim = range(1,4), xaxt="n")
plotCI(df$mean,y=NULL, uiw=df$upperlimit-df$mean, liw=df$mean-df$lowerlimit, err="y",      
    pch=20,  scol = "black", add=TRUE)
abline(a= 0, b= 0, col="red", lty=3)
axis(side=1, at=1:4, labels=c("noon", "3pm", "6pm", "9pm"))
```

[image]